# Angular js use data from resolve in another function

Tags: angularjs

i am not there yet in angular . I am trying to use data i pulled from my database from this function  myContributionPage() and use the id value in my myNo function but am getting undefined myContributionPage.id

```
(function(angular, $, _) {

    angular.module('pcp').config(function($routeProvider) {

        $routeProvider.when('/pcp', {
            controller: 'PcppcpCtlr',
            templateUrl: '~/pcp/pcpCtlr.html',

            // If you need to look up data when opening the page, list it out
            // under "resolve".
            resolve: {
                myPcp: function(crmApi) {
                    return crmApi('Pcp', 'get', '');
                },
                myContributionPage: function(crmApi) {
                    return crmApi('Contribution_page', 'get', '');
                },
                myNo: function(crmApi) {
                    return  crmApi('Contribution', 'getcount',{ contribution_page_id: Contribution_page.id});//my problem not working
                }
            }
        });
    });

    // The controller uses *injection*. This default injects a few things:
    //   $scope -- This is the set of variables shared between JS and HTML.
    //   crmApi, crmStatus, crmUiHelp -- These are services provided by civicrm-core.
    //   myContact -- The current contact, defined above in config().
    angular.module('pcp').controller('PcppcpCtlr', function($scope, crmApi, crmStatus, crmUiHelp,myPcp,myContributionPage,myNo) {

        // The ts() and hs() functions help load strings for this module.
        var ts = $scope.ts = CRM.ts('pcp');

        var hs = $scope.hs = crmUiHelp({file: 'CRM/pcp/pcpCtlr'}); // See: templates/CRM/pcp/pcpCtlr.hlp

        // We have myContact available in JS. We also want to reference it in HTML.
        $scope.myPcp = myPcp.values;
        //$scope.myContribution = myContribution;
        $scope.myContributionPage = myContributionPage.values;
        $scope.myNo=myNo;
    });

})(angular, CRM.$, CRM._);
```

Comment: seems like its angularjs instead of angular2 ?!

Comment: yes a mistake its angular

Comment: First of all, you are not injecting dependencies in the correct way into your controller `PcppcpCtlr`. Check the documentation and correct it (I don't have an example at hand, but it should be something like: `angular.module('pcp').controller('PcppcpCtlr', '$scope',[function($scope,...){...}])`.